# Problems rendering rmarkdown from shared drive

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm unable to render a markdown file when my RMD file is on a shared drive. I'm using rmarkdown version 1.12, R version 3.5.3, 64-bit Windows 10, pandoc 2.7.1.

I can not render to html, pdf or a word doc.

This fails (there are no spaces or punctuation in my folder path):

```
rmarkdown::render("//cor.local/subfolders/Martin/aNewRMD.RMD")
```

But this succeeds:

```
rmarkdown::render("C:/Users/Martin/Documents/aNewRMD.RMD")
```

(I'm just using the default new .RMD file that RStudio opens up).

Error message:

```
processing file: aNewRMD.RMD
  |.........                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                              |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |............................                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....................................                            |  57%
label: cars
  |..............................................                   |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................................         |  86%
label: pressure (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: aNewRMD.knit.md

"C:/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS aNewRMD.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output aNewRMD.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\Martin\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGoqMWG\rmarkdown-str421411883120.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" 
pandoc.exe: aNewRMD.utf8.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
```

Comment: Do you have `write` access in that shared folder?

Comment: Yes I have write access there

Comment: I don't know of R functions that understand that type of URI: `//servername/path/to/file`. (I might easily be wrong, but I've never seen it working.) One issue I believe is that R does not speak SMB (samba, cifs, etc). Suggestion: either serve it over another network protocol such as http/https/ftp (i.e., a protocol that R speaks sufficiently), or make sure you map the drive and access the shared directory by drive letter.

Comment: Aha! That was it. I mapped the shared drive to a letter. render("G:/blahblah.rmd") works just fine. If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that R does not know (yet) how to speak arbitrary URIs for network shares. Though I'm guessing that some functions (and other packages) might support other schemes, the [`download.file`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.3/topics/download.file) help page says

```
 The function 'download.file' can be used to download a single file
 as described by 'url' from the internet and store it in
 'destfile'.  The 'url' must start with a scheme such as 'http://',
 'https://', 'ftp://' or 'file://'.
```

What you are doing with `"//cor.local/subfolders/Martin/aNewRMD.RMD"` is telling it to speak a windows file sharing protocol (smb, cifs, etc) to a host named `cor.local` (somehow authenticating) and navigate to the respective sub-directory.

My suggestion: make windows deal with the basic authentication ahead of time, and "mount" it so that every app on your local computer will see it as "local" but mounting it to a drive letter:

```
C:\Users\AM4337> net use /user:yourdomain\youruser g: \\cor.local\subfolders
```

(it should ask for your password), and then working with/on it locally with

```r
R> rmarkdown::render("G:/Martin/aNewRMD.RMD")
```

Comment: @r2evans I'm having the same trouble: I can knit to a local drive but not to a network location.  Can you please expand on your answer?  I am not sure if your answer is something that must be repeated for each Rmarkdown file or if this a "permanent" fix. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, I don't know how to expand on this answer: (1) it's relatively clear in suggesting the command line needed to generate a local-appearing drive letter, `g:`; (2) I know nothing about your situation. This is a generic solution that provides one drive letter for one network location; it will work for any Rmd file that needs to be saved to that specific network location (or a subdir of it). It most likely need to be redone each time you login, though there are ways to make it quasi-permanent/recurring.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with multiple users trying to run an existing R process after an organisational upgrade to windows 10: 'Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1'.

Changing the project folder to an RStudio project solved the issue. An RStudio project sets its own working directory using the local path for each user, so replaces the network path with a local, lettered, path. Thanks @r2evans for explaining the issue and enabling this workaround.

(Apologies for the separate answer, I do not have the reputation to comment on @r2evans answer.)